# Problems using PC as a media server with PS3

Tags: wireless-networking, ps3, media-server, connection

I recently got a PS3 and decided to take advantage of the fact that it can be used to stream movies by making my PC a media server. I've done this in the past with the same router I have now before I sold my old PS3, but not on this PC. I've tried using both Tversity and PS3 Media server, but I don't think the problem lies within the configuration of either of those programs because I am unable to ping the PS3.

This problem only occurs when I am using a wired connection on my pc, attempting to connect to a WLAN connection on the PS3. If I switch to WLAN on my PC I can successfully ping the PS3 and connect to the media server.

Thanks

Comment: Is the wireless network and the wired network setup as two different domain/networks?  Perhaps a Virtual Network for the wireless?  Also more info about the router would be nice.

Comment: @Kronos I don't think so, how would I check? I'm the only one that really configures anything as far as the router is concerned and I don't recall setting up a separate network for the wireless. It's possible though. The only thing that has actually changed from when it was working before is that now the wired connection is routed through the electrical system via homeplugs instead of going directly from router to PC via the Ethernet cable.

Comment: I have access to the router config obviously so what do you need to know? It's one of these: http://www.belkin.com/support/product/?lid=en&pid=f5d8231-4&scid=221

Comment: One obvious tell: check the IP addresses of both the wired PC and the WLAN PS3 and make sure they're on the same subnet. (ie. they should both have the same first three octets, 192.168.0., for example)

Comment: "The only thing that has actually changed from when it was working before is that now the wired connection is routed through the electrical system via homeplugs instead of going directly from router to PC via the Ethernet cable." Are you sure that those are connected to the network or wired correctly?

Comment: Yep. I'm connected and typing this message right now using them.

Comment: Wow, well I'm sorry but the only thing that I can think of is that they are both on separate networks somehow.

Comment: Can you POST the IP adresses and subnet masks of the PC and the PS3 here please?

Comment: PC: 192.168.2.6 PS3: 192.168.2.7

Answer (score 1):

Since both the PS3 and the PC have IP addresses and they are within the same domain, my guess is that there are either firewall or port forwarding issues.  Here are some tips to try:

- Check firewall settings on windows and make sure that the system is allowing communication to the PS3
- Check the port forwarding of the system.  If you had port forwarding setup with the previous PS3 you'll have to redo with the new one.
- Placing the PS3 in a Demilitarized Zone (DMZ) may clear up port issues (Check this [forum](http://boardsus.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Network/Unofficial-PLAYSTATION-Network-Guide/m-p/27459694) guide and search for "DMZ")